# Blender scale settings issue

Tags: settings

I am new to blender and have been trying to setup blender 3.2 to use mm instead of meters as it default scale for me to create some custom parts and stop motion puppet parts and heads . I have looked at several online tutorials and followed them but each time I reopen blender the default settings are returned to meters any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: DId you try to save the blender preferences after you changfe it? Go to edit- preferences and in the botton you'll find save preferenes.

Comment: Open Blender with the default settings, then set up your Scene Properties (units, etc.) plus enabling addons, Render Engine, etc. Then go to File > Defaults > Save Startup File. The next time you start Blender all your settings should already be set.